# Ubuntu software center isn't opening!

Tags: software-center

I have tried some solutions from the internet but still not working. I have tried to open it in terminal and I get this:

```
12:43:40:0155 Gtk Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
12:43:40:0157 Gtk Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
12:43:40:0217 Gs  enabled plugins: desktop-categories, fwupd, os-release, packagekit, packagekit-local, packagekit-offline, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-refine-repos, packagekit-refresh, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-url-to-app, appstream, desktop-menu-path, hardcoded-blacklist, hardcoded-popular, modalias, odrs, packagekit-refine, rewrite-resource, packagekit-history, provenance, snap, systemd-updates, generic-updates, provenance-license, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
12:43:40:0217 Gs  disabled plugins: dpkg, dummy, fedora-langpacks, fedora-pkgdb-collections, repos
12:43:40:0375 Gs  /etc/PackageKit/Vendor.conf file not found
12:43:40:0847 Gtk Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /snap/snap-store/433/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /snap/snap-store/433/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can I fix this?
I am using Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Comment: Software center comes in two versions, a snap version and a "traditional" version that you can install via apt. You can try to install the traditional version by using "sudo apt install ubuntu-software" (in CLI, without double quote). In this way you will have two different stores (and you can afterwards remove the snap version that is a little buggy, like I did in my machine)

Comment: @LorenzKeel It works :) Thank you so much!

Comment: good to hear, I'll put it as answer.

Comment: What is the output of `ubuntu-software` in terminal. Does it display any errors?

Answer (score 8):

The issue is the snap-store is unable to load it's database for the first time. You need to remove then reinstall the snap:

```
sudo snap remove snap-store
sudo snap install snap-store
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on 20.10. Following a comment in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store-desktop/+bug/1870774), I was able to fix it by removing the pixbuf loaders cache at `~/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gdk-pixbuf-loaders.cache`.

I haven't had any of the subsequent issues that comment mentions, I'm assuming it's because I specifically removed the pixbuf-loaders cache and didn't wipe all the cache out like they did.

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 20.04 the Software Center application comes in two versions:

- a "traditional" version that you can install via apt.
- a snap version, that doesn't work as good as the previous one.

You can try to install the traditional version by using in a terminal the command:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-software
```

In this way you will have two different stores: if the one installed with apt works without issues, you may think to remove the snap one with the command:

```
sudo snap remove snap-store
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04.1. It happened after re-installation system with existing `/home` directory. I've tried to run from command line `snap-store` and got the same error.
Re-Installation of program helped to me:

```
sudo snap refresh snap-store
```