Ubuntu Software app and Snap Store app do not work
For a year now 2 applications to install applications in Ubuntu (Ubuntu Software & Snap Store) do not load the application catalog. When I try to do a search, it hangs all the time. I have to go to the terminal to install the applications. is there any way to make it work again? I am using Ubuntu version 22.04.4 LTS

try sudo snap refresh snap-store first from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248195/ubuntu-software-center-isnt-opening

and if one of that answers in the link helps you, please push the up button next to it.

Remove snap store from terminal sudo snap remove snap-store, and install gnome-software with sudo apt install gnome-software.

If you're using Wayland, try picking "Ubuntu on X.org" on the login screen instead.
